# How to convert a dataframe with daily returns to a dataframe index starting at 100

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('Daily Returns.xlsx', sheet_name='1')
```

My input dataframe:

```
       FECHA  TIGR US EQUITY  AMC US EQUITY  BBBY US EQUITY  BB US EQUITY
0 2019-03-14             NaN            NaN             NaN           NaN
1 2019-03-15             NaN       0.001381       -0.046092           NaN
2 2019-03-19             NaN      -0.016667       -0.002143           NaN
3 2019-03-20        0.365000       0.014237       -0.026485           NaN
4 2019-03-21       -0.043040       0.030749        0.022794           NaN
5 2019-03-22        0.035407      -0.023346       -0.015097     -0.036325
6 2019-03-25        0.044362       0.015936        0.012409     -0.021064
```

Desired dataframe:

```
       FECHA  TIGR US EQUITY  AMC US EQUITY  BBBY US EQUITY  BB US EQUITY
0 2019-03-14      100.000000     100.000000      100.000000    100.000000
1 2019-03-15      100.000000     100.138100       95.390800    100.000000
2 2019-03-19      100.000000      98.469098       95.186378    100.000000
3 2019-03-20      136.500000      99.871003       92.665366    100.000000
4 2019-03-21      130.625040     102.941936       94.777581    100.000000
5 2019-03-22      135.250081     100.538654       93.346724     96.367500
6 2019-03-25      141.250045     102.140838       94.505063     94.337615
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired behavior using [`cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```py
from numpy import nan
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'FECHA': ['2019-03-14', '2019-03-15', '2019-03-19', '2019-03-20', '2019-03-21', '2019-03-22', '2019-03-25'],
    'TIGR US EQUITY': [nan, nan, nan, .365, -.04304, .035407, .044362],
    'AMC US EQUITY': [nan, .001381, -.016667, .014237, .030749, -.023346, .015936],
    'BBBY US EQUITY': [nan, -.046092, -.002143, -.026485, .022794, -.015097, .012409],
    'BB US EQUITY': [nan, nan, nan ,nan, nan, -.036325, -.021064]
})

change_cols = ['TIGR US EQUITY', 'AMC US EQUITY', 'BBBY US EQUITY', 'BB US EQUITY']
df[change_cols] = (df[change_cols].cumsum() + 1) * 100
df[change_cols] = df[change_cols].fillna(100.0)
print(df)
```

Thanks to [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66213763/12998205) for pointing out a better way of dealing with columns to update :)

output:

```py
        FECHA  TIGR US EQUITY  AMC US EQUITY  BBBY US EQUITY  BB US EQUITY
0  2019-03-14        100.0000       100.0000        100.0000      100.0000
1  2019-03-15        100.0000       100.1381         95.3908      100.0000
2  2019-03-19        100.0000        98.4714         95.1765      100.0000
3  2019-03-20        136.5000        99.8951         92.5280      100.0000
4  2019-03-21        132.1960       102.9700         94.8074      100.0000
5  2019-03-22        135.7367       100.6354         93.2977       96.3675
6  2019-03-25        140.1729       102.2290         94.5386       94.2611
```

Keep in mind that values don't match exactly since I just have the first 6 decimal places from your preview, so there will be slight inaccuracies compared to the real data :)